# Jquery UniForm dont clear input after hit back button

Tags: jquery, uniform

Hi guys i'm using **jquery uniform plugin** for styling form, but im having a problem with Chrome and Safari, after hit browser back button all fields (checkbox's) remain checked (Safari and Chrome)

Any idea please?

Thanks guys.